# Find an element and return the XPath to it using Python

Tags: python, xpath, libxml2, python-2.x

I'm using Python 2.4/2.5, with `libxm2dom`. I can import an HTML document, and build the DOM. Is there a way to programmatically "search" for a given term, and be able to craft the XPath function to extract the `href` for the term? For example, given this chunk of HTML from the document:

```
...
<a href="dog">bigdog</a>
...
```

I'd like to have an XPath function that would find `bigdog`, and return the XPath to get the `href` link.

Comment: If you want to use libxml2 from Python, you should really use lxml.  It provides a much more powerful and convenient API than classical DOM.

Comment: Please work on asking questions in a clear, concise manner...see my edits of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPATH will select the `@href` of the `a` element who's text is "bigdog".

```
//a[text()='bigdog']/@href
```

Comment: hey mads,

thanks.. should have been more clear. i was actually looking for a way to accomplish a regex, and to be able to create an XPath which would then get them element based on the regex function...

something like 
    //a[text()='regex()']/@href

Comment: libxml2dom only supports XPATH 1.0, so XPATH 2.0 functions like matches() (which support regex) are out. Not sure if it has support for EXSLT.  If so, then you could use REGEX in the exslt:match() function. http://www.exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/index.html  Apparently, lxml supports EXSLT extensions, so you could use that if needed.